# Finding the sum of a set of calculated sums

Tags: mysql

I am developing a php/mysql database.
I have a table called ‘actions’ which (amongst others) contains fields hrs, mins, actiondate, invoiceid and staffid.

For any particular actiondate there could be any number of actions carried out by various staff who would enter their time as hrs and mins.

What I need to do is produce a table which for each date and for a specific member of staff and invoice, adds up all of the hrs and mins for each date as a decimal, rounds it up to the nearest quarter and displays that result. I also need to be able to add up all of those results and display that total.

For example, if on March 1st, person with staffid=23 had carried out 4 actions for invoiced 121 lasting, 1h2m, 23m, 10m and 20m  the total for that day would be 62+23+10+20 = 115m = 115/60 = 1.92 which would be rounded up to 2.00.

I can get each day’s total (maybe not very elegantly) and display it against the date using the code below

```
SELECT actions.`actiondate`,     
       (FORMAT((((CEIL((((60*SUM(hrs))+SUM(mins))/60)*4))/4)),2)) AS dayfeeqtr 
FROM   actions 
WHERE  staff.staffid=’23’ 
       AND invoiceid=‘121’ 
GROUP BY actions.`actiondate`
```

However, what I can’t work out, is how can I add up all of these rounded up results for that invoice and that member of staff.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Insert the results of your query in a table and SUM + GROUP BY over that table. So sort of repeat what is already in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT sum(dayfeeqtr)
FROM (SELECT a.`actiondate`,     
             FORMAT((((CEIL((((60*SUM(hrs))+SUM(mins))/60)*4))/4)), 2) AS dayfeeqtr 
      FROM actions a
      WHERE s.staffid = '23' AND invoiceid = '121'
      GROUP BY a.`actiondate`
     ) a;
```

I do note that your query is not correct -- for instance, there is a reference to `staff`, which is not in a `from` clause.  However, you say that this is working, so I assume the errors are a transcription problem.

Comment: Brilliant - that worked exactly as I wanted. Very many thanks.